# Google Calendar API - How an attendee can edit its answer status?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I fetch some events from a user's calendar. For each of them, a Participation entity is creating from event's attendees. In my application, I want them to be able to edit their answer's status.

On the v3 API, the endpoint to edit an event is `/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventId}`, but I know only the `{calendarId}` of the guy who fetched the meetings, so the other attendees cannot edit their participation if the calendar is not shared amongst them... They must edit it in their own calendar. so how can I edit this informations without pulling it again from Google, hence going through all their calendars to pull the right event again, from their point of view ?

How it's possible to edit the answer status for them ?

Comment: You cant edit there status with out them having authenticated your application and given you access to there calendars.

Comment: I have their auth credentials, the eventId, but not their calendarId. The only way I found is to fetch events across all their calendar to find the couple calendar/event. But it's weird and bad practical :(